# Cordova Android how to stop audio on pause?

Tags: android, cordova, audio, onpause

a colleague of me made a crossplattform game app with Cordova. now he is in vacation and I have the problem, that the background music of the app is still playing, if you press the home button and leave the app. Also if you make a phone call.

I tried to set the Android `<preference name="KeepRunning" value="false"/>`and also to true, but that didn't help.

Any idea what to do, to handle this problem?

Comment: no need to mention who previously work and why you working now.
share some code. using what audio is playing in app?

Comment: we are using some kind of HTML5 sound library, which is able to play more than one sound at once.

Answer (score 3):

I found an anwser by myself:

we had to set `<preference name="KeepRunning" value="true"/>` and then add this events:

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
    document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
}

function onPause() {
    // Handle the pause event
    // Set loudness to zero
}

function onResume() {
    // Handle the resume event
    // Set loudness to one

}
```

If KeepRunning is set to false, Cordova does not recognize the onPause/onResume events.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was, that the onPause event war fired AFTER the application resumes. -.-
But I could figure out a small hack which works. At least for me:

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
        if (document.hidden) {
            //onPause stuff
        } else {
            //onResume stuff
        }

    }, false);
```

This works for me on Android when the game minimized, the device turns off, or the tab is switched.

Answer (score 1):

Use the cordova `pause` event:

```
document.addEventListener('pause', function() {
  // Tell your audio library to pause here
});
```

When the user re-opens the app, the `resume` event will fire:

```
document.addEventListener('resume', function() {
  // Tell your audio library to start playing again
});
```

Comment: thanks I got it with the same result a few minutes ago. :-)